# Chunk Sort a Sequence

Tags: code-golf, array, sorting

Your task is to input a sequence of integers and chunk sort it. You may assume the input list can always be chunked into groups of 1, 2, and 3.

## Definition

*Chunk sorting* (a term I made up for the purpose of this challenge) is the action of first chunking a sequence into groups of 1, 2, and 3 in a cycle and then sorting each group.

## Test cases

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] => [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9]]
[5, 9, -2, 8, -6, 4, 5, 9, 1] => [[5], [-2, 9], [-6, 4, 8], [5], [1, 9]]
[8, 3, -1, 6, -8, 7, -1] => [[8], [-1, 3], [-8, 6, 7], [-1]]
```

## Scoring

The shortest code wins!

## Rules

No standard loopholes, please.

Comment: An invitation to look for nonstandard loopholes!

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
3Rṁx@JṢƙ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9846OHOxgoHr4c7Fx2b@f9w@9FJD3fO0Iz8/z/aUEfBSEfBWEfBREfBVEfBTEfBXEfBQkfBMlZHIRooYKmjoGsEFtE1gykCihmCpC3AGnUNwdp0LcBadQ1jAQ)

### How it works

```
3Rṁx@JṢƙ - Main link. Takes L on the left
3R       - [1,2,3]
  ṁ      - Mold to length L, repeating
     J   - Yield [1,2,...,len(L)]
   x@    - Repeat 1 once, 2 twice, 3 thrice, 4 once, 5 twice, etc.
      Ṣƙ - Sort chunks of L, grouped by the elements of [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,...]
```

Comment: [Interesting variant](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/UyOnhzsZDOw@3PNy56NjM/4fbj056uHOGZuT//9GGOgpGOgrGOgomOgqmOgpmOgrmOgoWOgqWsToK0UABSx0FXSOwiK4ZTBFQzBAkbQHWqGsI1qZrAdaqaxgLAA)

Answer (score 12):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 49 bytes

```ruby
->l{x=5;l.chunk{441[(x+=1)%12]}.map{|a,b|b.sort}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcpLCsIwGATgvaf4N4LiJJA06QOJFwlZNEIRrLVUC5U0Z49RcTXMfDPN/pU6k9ipD4vRx56fL/NwDUoJu1sORuy3QrrIb@0Y1hZ@9fxxn54xppE6awUkCiholKhQo3Fu8wUNakBMguocJUiBfpv4XzIU2QQoM8ut@jTn0hs)

Literally: chunk, then sort.

The magic number 441 is a bitmask with 1,2,3 binary digits alternatively seto to 1 or 0:

```ruby
000 11 0 111 00 1
```

Since there are only 2 binary digits, I can't make it 3 chunks, so I make it 6 and so I use mod 12 to rotate.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
3LI∍£€{ʒgĀ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f2MfzUUfvocWPmtZUn5qUfqTh//9oUx1LHV0jHQsdXTMdEx0QzzAWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@koGunoGRf@d/Yp/JRR@@hxY@a1lSfmpR@pOF/rc7/6GhDHSMdYx0THVMdMx1zHQsdy1gdhWhTHUsdXSMgT9cMLGWpYwgStgCq1DUEKtS1AKrVBYsZAhUAxQyNYmMB).

Or alternatively (thanks to *@ovs* for `N6%tò`):

```
.yN6%tò}€{
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fr9LPTLXk8KbaR01rqv//jzbVsdTRNdKx0NE10zHRAfEMYwE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@koGunoGRf@V@v0s9MteTwptpHTWuq/@v8j4421DHSMdYx0THVMdMx17HQsYzVUYg21bHU0TUC8nTNwFKWOoYgYQugSl1DoEJdC6BaXbCYIVABUMzQKDYWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
3L          # Push list [1,2,3]
  I∍        # Extend the [1,2,3] list to the same size as the input-list
    £       # Split the (implicit) input-list into those parts,
            # which includes trailing empty lists at the end
     €{     # Sort each inner list
       ʒgĀ  # Remove the empty lists:
       ʒ    #  Filter the list of lists:
        gĀ  #   Check if the list-length is not 0
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)

.y          # Adjacent group the (implicit) input-list by:
  N         #  Push the 0-based group-by index
   6%       #  Modulo-6
     t      #  Take the square-root of that
      ò     #  Round it to the nearest integer
 }€{        # After the group-by: sort each inner list
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

The `N6%tò` results in the sequence `[0,1,1,2,2,2,0,1,1,2,2,2,...]`, causing the adjacent group-by to split the input-list into parts of sizes `[1,2,3,1,2,3,...]`, which is what we want.

---

The first program could be 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) if the input-length is guaranteed to be \$n>1\$:

```python
3LI∍£€{Ô¨
```

[See all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@koGunoGRf@d/Yp/JRR@@hxY@a1lQfnnJoxX@d/9HRhjpGOsY6JjqmOmY65joWOpaxOgrRpjqWOrpGQJ6uGVjKUscQJGwBVKlrCFSoawFUqwsWMwbqBzPARGwsAA), and how it unfortunately fails for `[1]`. (Adding `Ć` after `I` would fix that edge-case, but unfortunately we'll then have another 10-bytes alternative.)

Comment: I haven't found anything shorter yet, but there are [a lot of interesting 12-byters](https://tinyurl.com/n7pm6atv) using the `.y ... }€{` approach, where `.y}` is an adjacent group-by and `€{` is a sort-each. Here a test battery if anyone wants to try to find something very short [for the inner portion](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVnlopb2SwqO2SQpK9qaH557b@v/QOr2w/7U6//3MVO30Dm06vJ4LxDq0veTwJhDr8Iwkw0OLuB41LDI8vPDQXiDtd3gF19F9UUDesmogGwA) which could be any repeating `abbccc` pattern based on index `N`.

Comment: `N6%tò` works for another 10-byter, but I doubt this approach can be any shorter

Answer (score 8):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
mOC¢ḣ3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P9ff@dCihzsWG////z/aVMdSR9dIx0JH10zHRAfEM4wFAA)

**How?**

```
    ḣ3      # 1..3
   ¢        # repeated infinitely;
  C         # now split the input into sublists
            # of these lengths (discarding any 
            # extra, unused lengths);
m           # finally, for each sublist:
 O          # sort it.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 10 bytes

```
J%6B§=1ÄṢƙ
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCJKJTZCwqc9McOE4bmixpkiLCIiLCIiLFsiWzUsIDksIC0yLCA4LCAtNiwgNCwgNSwgOSwgMV0iXV0=)

```
J%6B§=1ÄṢƙ  Main Link
J           [1, 2, 3, ..., len(input)]
 %6         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...]
   B        Binary; [[1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0], ...]
    §       Sum each; [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, ...]
     =1     Equal to 1?; [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...]
       Ä    Cumulative sum; [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, ...]
        Ṣƙ  Sort chunks of the input grouped based on equal elements on the left side
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <sup><s>86</s> <s>65</s></sup> 63 bytes

```
def f(a,i=0):
 for x in a:a[i:i%3-~i]=sorted(a[i:i%3-~i]),;i+=1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY37VNS0xTSNBJ1Mm0NNK24FNLyixQqFDLzFBKtEqMzrTJVjXXrMmNti_OLSlJTNJCENHWsM7VtDaHG6CbaRpvqKFjqKOga6ShYACkzHQUTHQWImGEsF9AKTa6Cosy8EiADognmBgA)

Modifies the list in-place; kinda cursed.

Comment: I'm surprised that `l[a:b:c].sort()` doesn't work to sort a slice of a list in place.

Comment: @xnor I agree, it's a bit inconsistent that slicing on the LHS is a mutable reference, but makes a copy on the RHS.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,i=1:a and[sorted(a[:i])]+f(a[i:],i%3+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BasMwEETv/oq5lEhkXZDTJLZB/REhioptInBs4SgJ/XpXqziX3WHn7TDhL17mqVrXQY/u@ts5OPJatWlPnbnNS@w74UzrrbT7ISnfWvIfh72S6/Pixx6qLeCnQJjvMUDj6oLoH24kLO75k5x7FPLzFkYfxQ76GzspC4TFTxGDSL6E1vl5NYpQEQ6EL8KRcCKcCTWhsfxojLIEwwTvjWF55pE5W5h0bAhllT/L0zss3dQWc2ScgSaLF1Kzzo7agupcpVS5SFnnMuU7I@Ps5S7sctvX0dp/)

Answer (score 6):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-xp`, <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 18 bytes

```
$AL:SN*_^@^13Ma<>6
```

[Replit!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Or, here's a 20-byte equivalent in Pip classic (with a header to simulate the -x flag): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@B9mlWj9X8XRx6o62E8rMc4hztC41jfRxs7s////ugX/o02tLa11jawtrHXNrE2sQTzDWAA)

#### Explanation

```
$AL:SN*_^@^13Ma<>6
              a     First command-line arg
               <>6  Group into length-6 chunks
             M      Map this function to each chunk:
          ^13        Split 13 into a list of digits [1;3]
       _^@           Split the argument at those indices
    SN*              Sort each sublist using numeric comparison
$AL:                Fold the result on append-list (flattening by one level)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>70</s> <s>63</s> 59 bytes

```r
function(a)Map(sort,split(a,rep(l<-seq(!a)-1,l%%3+1)[l+1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jco9CoAwDEDh3VPEQUgwHeIfKl7BE4hDEQtC0drW81fB6cHH88nApJJ5zi0e14maZu0wXD5ycPaIqNnvDu2kwn5jrkkJ26KoS6HFlrISJYMyDpQZ3LBlGBhUxdB/6Rgaht/kG18)

Comment: Getting rid of `!` in `seq` and using `Map(sort,...)` (from your comment) matches Dominic's 59.

Comment: I think the `!` needs to be there for input of length one--Dominic's solution of using `[<-` neatly avoids that, but I think I can still tie it.

Comment: Does it actually work with [input of length one](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNR0zexQKM4v6hEp7ggJ7NEI1GnKLVAI8dGtzi1UEMxUVPH0MpYWzFHMzonVlPzf5qGueZ/AA) now, though?

Comment: Looks like it's back to the tie again. Anyway, well done!

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 53 bytes

```
Sort/@TakeList[#,i=0;UpTo@Mod[++i,4]&/@#]/.{}->Set@$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctBC4IwGMbx@z7FC4YX37VmZpMw9gEKAu0kHkYNG2GG7Tb22ZcNuv6f5zcq@9CjsuamwlCHZpotk6166pP52C5BU28O13c7yfN077LMYNGnTCY9WztPj422cpWGy2xeFpgcmHTEcYQcYYtQIOwQSoQ9gkCoPBK3hAqB5rHQ8n9aGv/NIkLKI6MiUso98SF8AQ)

-6 bytes thanks to @alephalpha
-3 bytes thanks to @theorist
-2 bytes thanks to @att

Comment: Tips: `NestWhile` can always be replaced by `//.`: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYtNC4IwGIDv/ooXgi6@a0zLtDJ2joIgb6IxSmyICnO3Mf/6skHX56MX@tP0QsuXcG3uHqPSlBeia65y0uWUr9B0ObOUbsSTHgvFxalQJaun6nC@jHIoxRKE4Xwb33NsQ1ZVa3dXctBAeUu5CQxDiBBihC3CDiFB2COkCJnFwCwgQyCRJyT5RwtjP536kTC/kdSvhNnAOvcF "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: –3 bytes: `Sort/@TakeList[#,Take[Join@@Table[Range@3,q=Tr[1^#]],⌈q/2⌉]]&` https://tio.run/##NcvBC4IwFMfxu3/FA6HTG2Napgdh5@gQ5W0sWDHWKBVtN/Fe4F/pP7J00O3xeb9vrdxD18rZu/Km9Je2d5RX6qmP9u1EjOspDq1t@KK3lxZn1RjNU@zKqhfsGkuJ8/TpaDJPXyk3/tTbxgHlhvIhGhhCgpAibBF2CBnCHiFHKEaMhgUKBJIEIdl/tBhb33kICQsZyUNK2BiN3v8A

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##NctBC4IwGMbx@z7FC4YX37WmZZMw9gEKAu0kHkYNG2GG7Tb22ZcNuv6f5zcq@9CjsuamwlCHZpotk6166pP52C5BU28O13c7yfN077LMYIG8T5lMerZ2nh4bbeUqDZfZvCwwOTDpiOMIOUKBsEXYIZQIewSBUHkkbgkVAs1joeX/tDT@m0WElEdGRaSUe@JD@AI) assuming input is nonempty, [56](https://tio.run/##NctBC4IwGMbxu5/iBcGLz1jTMiWEQdeCIDuJyCixEWbobmOffZnQ9f88v0GZZzcoo@/K96W/jpPh8qjmbq4r9epOejZ1CF1uDrdPNcrz@KjjWCOFaCIuwwa2bV0T@cuk34a47Lm0gRWgBJSCtqAdKAPtQTmocAjsEgoQS9bCsv9paeI35ytkYmUsXykTLnDefwE) if we can't.

Comment: actually, we can get another [-2](https://tio.run/##NctBC4IwGMbx@z7FC4YX37VmZpMw9gEKAu0kHkYNG2GG7Tb22ZcNuv6f5zcq@9CjsuamwlCHZpotk6166pP52C5BU28O13c7yfN077LMYNGnTCY9WztPj422cpWGy2xeFpgcmHTEcYQcYYtQIOwQSoQ9gkCoPBK3hAqB5rHQ8n9aGv/NIkLKI6MiUso98SF8AQ) from there

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 61 bytes

*-4 and -1 thanks to Arnauld*

```
x=>(f=n=>x+x&&[x.splice(0,++n).sort((w,z)=>w-z),...f(n%3)])``
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 59 bytes

```r
function(x,`*`=`[<-`)Map(sort,split(x,x*rep(seq(x),x*1:3)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfnFGal12cX1Ri@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCJ0ErwTYh2kY3QdM3sUADJK1TXJCTWQKUqtAqSgUKpRZqVGgCOYZWxpqamghjNAytLDW5ENxkDVMdBUsdBV0jHQULIGWmo2CiowARM9REVQmUNwYqMdRRAKrSBfLMQTyg6QA)

Comment: Hmm, I have 60 bytes if I use the `Map(sort,...)` instead of `lapply`. I'm catching up!

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 24 bytes

```
5,6,S`,
%,,2S`,
%N`[^,]+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/31THTCc4QYdLVUfHCEz7JUTH6cRqg2QsdXSNdCx0dM10THRAPEMA) Explanation:

```
5,6,S`,
```

Split the input into groups of up to six values. Limits are 0-indexed in Retina 1, so the first six values are numbered `0` to `5` and therefore the comma after the sixth value is also numbered `5`, however subsequent splits are every six commas as expected, until the end of the input.

```
%,,2S`,
```

Split each group into groups of 1, 2 and 3 values (if possible). The syntax `,,2` is short for `,2,2` so it only splits on the first and third comma; `,2` would be a range and so would also split on the second comma.

```
%N`[^,]+
```

Sort the values in each group.

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash 4.4.23](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 142 bytes

```
f()(
i=1
a=("$@")
while [ ${#a[@]} -gt 0 ]
do
r=$r"["$(printf "%s\n" "${a[@]:0:$i}" |sort -n)"]"
a=("${a[@]:${i}}")
((i=i==3?1:i+1))
done
echo $r
)
```

[Try it here!](https://tio.run/##fc7PioMwEMfx@zzFjzSFhBJo@m9VCNv3cD3YVuvAEkt02YPrs7ux7bH0PN/5zJzKrpmmWmlF7CyVTgl5FJp@G/6ukEMOizI/FiPMtccaBV1aCk6GXKpbYN/XEMvuywsIOcxhts4kj@Kva0MP43XxIB8zOfA4Rlwpduzc9tNmvLJaR9RXVJ2bFjKQntjffnqnLDbYYoc9DvhAglQT1fOh@3z@ShA92z1SmE2MzOG@kcK@qZPoGhtZk0TZvEinfw)

### Explanation

```
i=1                                           > used to keep track of chunk size         
a=("$@")                                      > transforms the parameters as an array
while [ ${#a[@]} -gt 0 ]                      > while there is still some elements to "chuck sort"
do
r=$r[$(printf "%s\n" "${a[@]:0:$i}"|sort -n)] > construct the final result by picking only the required chunk from the array and sorts it. Store sort result in r and ad some delimiters
a=("${a[@]:${i}}")                            > remove processed chunk from the array
((i=i==3?1:i+1))                              > set size of next chunk
done
echo $r
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf. Nice first answer!

Comment: You don't need to make a copy of `"$@"`, although remember that parameter indices start at `1`, you can use `$#` for the number of parameters, and you can use `shift $i` to remove parameters. Also, `((i=i%3+1))` works to calculate the size of the next chunk.

Comment: @Neil I will check that out this week end. Thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

*-1 thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)*

```
∧¨⊢⊔˜¯1+`(0=∾↑↕3)⥊˜≠
```

Anonymous tacit function that takes an array of numbers as its right argument. [Run it online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oinwqjiiqLiipTLnMKvMStgKDA94oi+4oaR4oaVMynipYrLnOKJoAoKRiA14oC/OeKAv8KvMuKAvzjigL/CrzbigL804oC/NeKAvznigL8x)

#### Explanation

The explanation uses an example argument of `⟨ 8 3 ¯1 6 ¯8 7 ¯1 ⟩`:

```
∧¨⊢⊔˜¯1+`(0=∾↑↕3)⥊˜≠
          (      )      Generate the array ⟨ 1 1 0 1 0 0 ⟩:
               ↕3         Range(3): ⟨ 0 1 2 ⟩
              ↑           Prefixes: ⟨ ⟨⟩ ⟨ 0 ⟩ ⟨ 0 1 ⟩ ⟨ 0 1 2 ⟩ ⟩
             ∾             Join: ⟨ 0 0 1 0 1 2 ⟩
           0=              Equal 0: ⟨ 1 1 0 1 0 0 ⟩
                  ⥊˜   Reshape it to
                     ≠  the length of the argument: ⟨ 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 ⟩
        +`              Cumulative sum
      ¯1                starting at -1: ⟨ 0 1 1 2 2 2 3 ⟩
    ⊔˜                 Using that list as a categorizer, group
   ⊢                   the argument: ⟨ ⟨ 8 ⟩ ⟨ 3 ¯1 ⟩ ⟨ 6 ¯8 7 ⟩ ⟨ ¯1 ⟩ ⟩
∧¨                     Sort each: ⟨ ⟨ 8 ⟩ ⟨ ¯1 3 ⟩ ⟨ ¯8 6 7 ⟩ ⟨ ¯1 ⟩ ⟩
```

Comment: -2: ∧¨(+`0‿1‿0‿1‿0‿0⥊˜≠)⊸⊔

Comment: @Razetime That doesn't cycle correctly. For example, when reshaped to length 9, the 0/1 list should be `⟨ 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 ⟩`, but yours gives `⟨ 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 ⟩`.

Comment: ah ok, must not have seen it

Comment: [20 bytes](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oinwqjiiqLiipTLnMKvMStgKDA94oi+4oaR4oaVMynipYrLnOKJoAoKRiA14oC/OeKAv8KvMuKAvzjigL/CrzbigL804oC/NeKAvznigL8x) by using ```↑↕3``` instead of ```↕¨↕4```...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Ah, nice. `↕¨↕4` is a translation of how I would do it in Pip: `,,4`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
ẏǒʀÞṁvs
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuo/HksqAw57huYF2cyIsIiIsIls1LCA5LCAtMiwgOCwgLTYsIDQsIDUsIDksIDFdIl0=)

I'm way late to the party, but who cares when the program looks like it spells something with heavy skamtebord vibes.

### Explained

```
ẏǒʀÞṁvs
ẏ       # The range [0...len(input)]
 ǒ      # modulo each by 3 to get the chunk sizes
  ʀ     # cast each to range [0...n] for shape
   Þṁ   # mold the input to that, without repeating elements
     vs # sort each sublist
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>24</sup> 15 bytes

```
<@/:~/.~#$#\##\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BCsIwEETvfsVghCJsUlNtmxYFUfAkHry2IQexiBf/oL8eu5t6MJDssjvzmLzj0mQDDi0yEDZop6sNzvfrJe6PeTvmZlQr1SvVx/Xi@Xh9MMASCsKWsCOUhIpQExyhAXA7GXSd9YSONVxnFbc1P6z0/gebVg0hFEII1Q86zewMK9mkC3ZxkySOe9nYP5yTYMFKrOAkWrCQk3Di1HYOp136QBp6H78)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>48</s> 40 bytes

```
≔⮌ＡθＷθ⊞υＥ⊕﹪Ｌυ³⊟θＩＥυ✂⟦⌊ι⁻Σι⁺⌊ι⌈ι⌈ι⟧⁰χ⁻⁴Ｌι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5PC8IwDMXvfoocU4jgfxRP4klwMPQ4digzuELXzbVVv33NcB48JS/5vZdUte6rVtuUDt6bu8MLP7n3jCfXxYBKETzUfvKqjWXAh4I8@hojQaY7YaqeG3aBb5i1t2hbPLO7BwHEtxzMeduJS0lE3hsX8Kh9wMErEVdrKsYiM840sUEjuPTR43VUuRXxt9bvsVd/qiSYEcxnv4AVwfjIQA7nUyqKNcGOYLog2ErZEAj2nc3LMk2f9gM) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Charcoal really struggles here as it has no variable length split, flatten or sort primitive (at least not on TIO).

```
≔⮌Ａθ
```

Reverse the input array.

```
Ｗθ
```

Repeat until the input array has been chunked.

```
⊞υＥ⊕﹪Ｌυ³⊟θ
```

Create a chunk of size depending on the number of chunks so far.

```
ＩＥυ✂⟦⌊ι⁻Σι⁺⌊ι⌈ι⌈ι⟧⁰χ⁻⁴Ｌι
```

For each chunk, get the minimum, middle and maximum elements, but skip the middle if the chunk's size is less than `3` and skip the maximum if its size is less than `2`.

Previous 48-byte version didn't require the input to be completely chunkable:

```
ＷθＦ³«⊞υ✂θ⁰⊕κ≔✂θ⊕κＬθ¹θ»ＩＥΦυι✂⟦⌊ι⁻Σι⁺⌊ι⌈ι⌈ι⟧⁰χ⁻⁴Ｌι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7LCsIwEDzbr9jjBlawvlA8iSAICgWPpYdQYxtMo01SFcRvj6kv6GHZmd3ZnclLbvIzV97fSqkEYM3geDaAIwaPqJc0tsSGYK9kLrAmGBBsdG5EJbQTBzwxxhZRb2mtLDT@VV0JwVbowpXhN0Ecqg43zygxUjtccetwxy@4lsoJ05pJ9jNMd1LLqqmwHQXcWNx/WaIC6az5/YtZh2Xv0PHg92D8j9Mq2/zep@mEYE7QHxLMQpsSBNlnFmeZ71/VCw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗθ
```

Repeat until the input is empty.

```
Ｆ³«
```

Take three chunks.

```
⊞υ✂θ⁰⊕κ
```

Save the chunk.

```
≔✂θ⊕κＬθ¹θ
```

Remove the chunk from the input.

```
»ＩＥΦυι✂⟦⌊ι⁻Σι⁺⌊ι⌈ι⌈ι⟧⁰χ⁻⁴Ｌι
```

For each non-empty chunk, get the minimum, middle and maximum elements, but skip the middle if the chunk's size is less than `3` and skip the maximum if its size is less than `2`.

Answer (score 2):

## [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
?.(1(%(0,.))('?(2,.)(+(?(<,<),
).1
```

[Try it!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=Py4oMSglKDAsLikpKCc/KDIsLikoKyg/KDwsPCksCikuMQ__&a=KDUgOSAtMiA4IC02IDQgNSA5IDEp)

#### Explanation

The first line is a recursive function that does most of the work. It takes two arguments, a list and an integer, where the integer represents the current chunk size (1, 2, or 3).

```
?.(1(%(0,.))('?(2,.)(+(?(<,<),
?                               If
 .                              Argument 1
                                is truthy (non-empty):
  (1                             Construct a list from
        ,                         Argument 2
      (0  )                       Take that many elements of
         .                        Arg1
    (%     )                      Sorted
                                 prepended to
            ('?                   Recursive call with two arguments:
               (2,.)               Drop (arg2) elements of arg1
                                  and
                    (+             Increment
                      (?            If
                          ,         Arg2
                        (<  )       is less than
                           <        3:
                             ,       Arg2
                                    Else, 0
                                Else, empty list
```

Then the main function on the second line is simply:

```
)    Call the previous function with these arguments:
 .    Argument 1 of the main function
     and
  1   1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
£ñ+Ü5▬
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9ca42b9a3516&i=%5B1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6,+7,+8,+9%5D+%0A%5B5,+9,+-2,+8,+-6,+4,+5,+9,+1%5D+%0A%5B8,+3,+-1,+6,+-8,+7,+-1%5D+&a=1&m=2)

Comment: first time use of `|/` in an answer?

Comment: I can't say I've seen it used anywhere before.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>73</s></sup> 70 bytes

```c
l;f(a,n)int*a;{for(l=0;n;n-=l,a+=l,l%=3)qsort(a,++l,4,L"\x62b078bǃ");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVJNj5swEL3vrxghpeLDVgPsZkld2kPVW/9BElWsY3bRsk6KkYo24tQf139VOtiAQdlDL0XCYL83M2@eh9NHzruuZLmbEekVsvYzdslPlVumayaZpGlJsgCXcpXG3g91qmpkBkFJbsk3Z99soof1ffLw@5fjsbbDeHjJCul6cLkBfPqDWqg63B0ghUtIICIQE7glcEdgQ@CeQEJg27KJGhkqwlsCNNI43YwheBbOyLEhJzopDXVKmui0FHkLDd@lIaviVZxyV8vy3g8732wJzNBoiUZLNF6isWfL@bqeMuV0YmJaM594Jkw0Z8FrcfxHg0a6Nal3aDs5lOiw8DrAGtW7FBuXNldG@VOA4U/yiC1tf8dG@EmqGvhTVvm4Cv4sKhOOA/I12jfbL/jeOQTm@9gZonHawO21FvIoGgxbs@H34@j3WNBaPp0wCALNHkdudFZipuHaNX5gcxivaMDVFXyukJC7zg5nejq0KgeFqE7q4vPC8/CVWh2x5@Jz3/gHB9d6VxxmKVub3K0JSO9awgHoJ1joMJeEGqaLeqM7OGdKISf8r/o1uS/0LtUQpKgKv291aBtaqb3EXOOc9AnGpO1N2/3heZk9qo7@7OiraARXdcaf/wI)

Inputs a pointer to an array of integers and its length (because pointers in C carry no length info).
Chunk sorts the array in place.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>76</s> 71 bytes

```
import Data.List
f=(%)1
n%[]=[]
n%x=sort(take n x):(mod n 3+1)%drop n x
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##FYq9CsMgGEX3PMVdBKVpQQJtKbhl7NZRHIQkRBJ/0K80b2/NdO453NWWbd73Wp1PMRNGS/b2doW6RXEmZBeYNkqbxkOV9uBktxkBh3hxH6e2hosUbMoxnbV66wIU0pc@lMHLGn/gC/Szx9DjKnvcG5o9TjNC1D8)

-5 bytes thanks to xnor

Calling f on a list chunk sorts it.

Comment: You can save a few bytes by defining `g` as an infix function: [TIO](https://tio.run/##FYq9CsMgGEX3PMVdBKVpQQJtKbhl7NZRHIQkRBJ/0K80b2/NdO453NWWbd73Wp1PMRNGS/b2doW6RXEmZBeYNkqbxkOV9uBktxkBh3hxH6e2hosUbMoxnbV66wIU0pc@lMHLGn/gC/Szx9DjKnvcG5o9TjNC1D8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Ah, I forgot about infix functions!  Thanks for the tip, xnor!

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), <s>194</s> <s>170</s> 146 bytes

```
(load library
(d C(q((L P)(i L(c(map head(zip L(1to P)))(i(e P 3)(C(t(t(t L)))1)(i(e P 2)(C(t(t L))3)(C(t L)2))))(
(d S(q((L)(map merge-sort(C L 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY6xDoMwEEN3vsLj3dAh0FKYWTMg8QVpiWgkKDRkoT9PL6FVlcV69tkJ7rmNbl32ncbZ9BjdzRu/ZdSjoReRRsvkoOlOk1nwsKant1sEqDCLx@KSRYuCqaEQH7RQ9eP5l0d6ZETlHA/jSJdGOJVP1g/2tM4@UAMNtVMHsRVyFDjjghJXVKizyOXTQVANetpBVsRIquQUraH@sUruk6lYOpKqWLoOtn8A)

-24 thanks to DLosc suggesting implementing `take` instead of the hodge-podge mess of `c`s I was using before. -24 again by implementing `take` more golfily.

Comment: @DLosc great suggestion, thanks! I'll definitely be keeping `list` in mind but looks like `take` was shorter here after all.

Comment: Hm, and with the library you can do a shorter version of `take`: `(d T(q((L N)(map head(zip L(1to N))))))`, which isn't recursive so it can just be inlined: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY6xDoMwEEN3vsLj3dAh0FKYWTMg8QVpiWgkKDRkoT9PL6FVlcV69tkJ7rmNbl32ncbZ9BjdzRu/ZdSjoReRRsvkoOlOk1nwsKant1sEqDCLx@KSRYuCqaEQH7RQ9eP5l0d6ZETlHA/jSJdGOJVP1g/2tM4@UAMNtVMHsRVyFDjjghJXVKizyOXTQVANetpBVsRIquQUraH@sUruk6lYOpKqWLoOtn8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 53 bytes

```
a->i=0;c=2;[vecsort(a[i+1..i=j+1])|b<-a,#a>j=i+c++%3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtRCsIwEAWvslSEhuwW02pNqelFQj7WYiVFNFQRBO8e04Cfb@ZN4MXTNcQJTGQavNn1o6l7@76Mz8fyKtl6qarKm1kqJ77nEzFueJiNl6OU28ZFDuH2KRlogLD4e0qgWEcBU8lCIFirEGqEBmGPcEBoEY4IGqFzySbQIVCdCbX/U2Jq1TqHpHJGOqeknBPxBw)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 131 bytes

```php
function(&$a){for($a=array_chunk($a,3),$i=-1;$a[++$i];sort($a[$i]))!$a[$i][1]|$i%3?:array_splice($a,$i,0,[[array_shift($a[$i])]]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7disIwEIXv@xQjjEuDEzDWn2osPkgIErpbGtQ2RCuIu89es3FXL/XuzDnzHY6rXb/euNolWBV91TXlybZN@oGGXavWp2gK4725bMu6a3bhpIwR2oILiUaNRmi1PLb@FBIVNGODu1BCf6MdZpvVHT@6vS2/fnm0NCal/uzaVg9WayZ/epkkGEIoQAmCCUFGMCWYEcwJFgQ5wVLLMDeF@MdkcjZ@@9kd3NN5VARsScAnkePz/6rgifdL8jiCiziB53EGf8n3Nw)

This is a first take, it feels awfully long, there has to be a better way.. damn these "array_" prefixes!