# Repeating slices of an array incrementally

Tags: code-golf, array

Let's say I have a non-empty list (array):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I want to incrementally slice the list into incremented amount of elements per chunk.

For this array, my desired output is:

```
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

What would be the best way to slice the array in multiple chunks.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Note: For the final chunk, if the number of elements left in `r` is less than what the incremented output requires, the last chunk should just be all that remains in the list.

## Test cases:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
-> [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]

l = [10, 20, 30, 40]
-> [[10], [20, 30], [40]]

l = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
-> [[100], [200, 300], [400, 500]]
```

Comment: I suggest adding a test case with repeated elements (or specifying that cannot happen in the input)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 40 bytes

```
f=lambda a,n=1:a and[a[:n]]+f(a[n:],n+1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JcpNCsIwEAbQq3zLhI5g6l8b6ElCFiMlGNBpKCnUs7jJRjyEC8_hbRSyepv3eKV7vkzSlvJccth0XxWGK9_OI4NJBmP_yujYWfG-CYqdWE_SGF3_O0wzVkRBUFHSkpXWNs1RMtY6yscZQkvYEfaEA-FIOBE6Qk8wW1_bDw)

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
żẇ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJBIiwiIiwixbzhuociLCIiLCJbMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNSwgNiwgNywgOCwgOSwgMTBdXG5bMTAsIDIwLCAzMCwgNDBdXG5bMTAwLCAyMDAsIDMwMCwgNDAwLCA1MDBdIl0=)

Upgrading got me like

### Explained

```
żẇ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ż   # ‎⁡The range [1, len(input)]
 ẇ  # ‎⁢Wrap the input list into chunks of each number. Stops grouping when there's no more items
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Razetime*

```
CN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/39nv////0YY6RjrGOiY6pjpmOuY6FjqWOoYGsQA)

```
C       # Cut off substrings of the following lengths:
 N      # natural numbers
```

Comment: `CN` should work

Comment: @Razetime - Oh, yeah, of course.  Doh.  Will you post that, then?

Comment: nah, it's not worth an extra answer. Add it in if you want to.

Comment: Wow 2 bytes... Is this language just made for this challenge?

Comment: @U12-Forward Husk is (also) a golfing language (see [its wiki](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki)).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Cool, looking into it.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
JÄ‘œṖ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/rcMujhhlHJz/cOe3/4fajkx7unPH/f7ShgYGOghGIMAYRJiDC1MAgFgA)**

#### How?

```
JÄ‘œṖ - Link: list, L                  e.g. [5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2]
J     - range of length of L                [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
 Ä    - cumulative sums                     [1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36]
  ‘   - increment                           [2,4,7,11,16,22,29,37]
   œṖ - partition L before those indices    [[5],[4,3],[2,1,0],[1,2]]
```

---

Also 5 bytes [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@rIuHQzmMz/x9uPzrp4c4Z//9HGxoY6CgYgQhjEGECIkwNDGIB):

```
Jx`¹ƙ
```

...(`J`) range of length, (`` ` ``) use right as both arguments with (`x`) repeat elements then (`ƙ`) apply to groups of identical values (`¹`) a no-op function.
i.e. build a list like `[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,...]` and group the original values like its equal values, `[[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],...]`.

or, equivalently (just reapplying `J` rather than using the quick `` ` ``):

```
JxJ¹ƙ
```

Comment: Wow!! 5 bytes, but just curious, there is `ÇŒṘ` in the footer, what does that do?

Comment: @U12-Forward The entry is a monadic function (AKA Link), but I want to avoid Jelly's full-program output formatting. `Ç` calls the Link above and `ŒṘ` formats the list in a Python style (Jelly's full-program output formatting shows singleton lists as the element they contain, so the example I give would _look_ like `[5,[4,3],[2,1,0],[1,2]]` instead. (Jelly's list representation also smashes characters or mixed type lists, so `[5,6,'a']` would be output as `56a` which doesn't matter here, but both can be useful since we usually have the option of writing a function or full program.)

Comment: Oh, got it! Thanks Jonathan.

Comment: Wow! Nice answer, 5 bytes... How?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Could you btw clarify and explain your two other answers :)

Comment: @richardec Jelly is a language for golfing. See "How?" and if interested see [the wiki](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah, Jelly is a language made for golfing, got it.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks for the explanation. Interested in Jelly, for golfing. Might want to learn some of it.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Btw, what is the source language of Jelly. Would be cool if there would be an existing converter from other programming languages. Like you write Python code, `range(len(L))` would be translated to `J` (in your answer) in Jelly, but it would be very hard to memorize all of these commands... Also `cumsum` would require Numpy or Pandas to do it in shorter ways, but instead Jelly can do `Ä`... Wouldn't it be nice if there was something to convert Python to Jelly?

Comment: @JonathanAllan What is `¹` in your answer btw... You said a "no-op function"... But not sure what it means... Btw thanks for all the help bothering with me trying to learn Jelly haha.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Also as I see here... ```"`"``` (without the quotes) and `J` are interchangeable in the last 2 examples?

Comment: @U12-Forward Jelly is written in Python - see the [github page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage). Commands are not _that_ hard to remember, and they are listed on the [wiki](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki). `¹` is a [no-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) - it is a monadic atom (one-argument function) that just gives you back what you pass it.

Comment: @U12-Forward Yes, `\`` is an instruction (a "[quick](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Quicks)") to pass the left argument as both the left and right arguments of a dyadic atom/link/chain (two-argument function); in this case we could use `J` a second time to give the same effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132666/discussion-between-jonathan-allan-and-u12-forward).

Comment: Thanks @JonathanAllan, I am trying my best to learn it.

Comment: @U12-Forward not sure about giving me the green checkmark when there is a 2-byte answer. (Note that often in code-golf people do not award the green check at all, since the competetion is really intra-language rather than inter-language anyway.)

Answer (score 6):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras math.unicode`, <sup><s>58</s></sup> 57 bytes

```
[ dup '[ _ index 1 + 2 * √ .5 + ⌊ ] group-by values ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LagIxGIX3PsXZCZWGeBmvm@6KGzfS1SAlZv4ZgzYZcxGH4r6UPkEfzxcZE8XF/8P3HTicUkhvbPuxXq7e59iT1XRAaRs4OgbSkhy@hN/dHyuDll4Z/XAsaCVNQaisCbXSFaOzt8JBOGekQ23J@6a2SnssOp1v9DHAECNkGGOCKWboc1xSwDHgGHKMnpxEMklxZPEubY4i1Ojm@ITSBZ1jXy82vuD68w@WRbj@/WLzmPO6bXAShxD3b1pv1RtyMMZinKC9AQ)

Group elements by the integer inverse triangular function of their indices. In other words, given a zero-based index \$i\$, its element belongs to group

$$\left\lfloor\sqrt{2(i + 1)} + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 38 bytes

```ruby
->l{(1..l.size).map{l.shift(_1)}-[[]]}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: Thanks @RedwolfPrograms

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 40 bytes

```hs
n![]=[]
n!x=take n x:(n+1)!drop n x
(1!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P08xOtY2OpYrT7HCtiQxO1UhT6HCSiNP21BTMaUovwDE/Z@bmJlnW1CUmVeiYqgYbainZ2QZ@x8A)

There seems like there should be a shorter way to do this maybe with scans or folds, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think this needs a newline and `(1!)` included in the byte count.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
≔⮌ＡθＷθ⊞υＥ⌊⟦Ｌθ⊕Ｌυ⟧⊟θＩυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYw7C4MwFEb3/oqM90IK6WtyKp0EBekqDsFeTECvmof9@WkCXc7wncM3Gu3GVc8pPb23E8ObDnKeoOYtBkCUYsfq9DV2JgE7ii56A1GKVm/QWrZLXKBviKdgspai5tHRQhzoA/85Ig7ZdOuWC8xvnbMc4KV9KK5Kqe8vSklxLbgV3AseSg1DOh/zDw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⮌Ａθ
```

Reverse the input list.

```
Ｗθ
```

Repeat until it is empty...

```
⊞υＥ⌊⟦Ｌθ⊕Ｌυ⟧⊟θ
```

... pop up to the next number of items from the input list into a new group.

```
Ｉυ
```

Output the grouped list.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

```r
function(x)split(x,rep(s<-seq(!x),s)[s])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfmZccX5RaEF@ck5mcavs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQrO4ICezRKNCByirUWyjW5xaqKFYoalTrBldHKuJqk/D0MrQQPM/AA)

Inspired by [Giuseppe's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238336/95126) to "[Chunk sort a sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/238329/95126)".

Comment: I thought this challenge felt familiar! Nicely done.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
</.~#{.#\##\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcsxDoJAFITh3lP8cQtiMqwPdhEkWplYWVnTGQmx8QAkXn1hG0MxXzGZ@aS9L0auPQXC6NeUntvzcU@Xo/@52bvBuSEddu/X9GWkErUIIopGnEQrOnEWlf1HRm0EI24qW5@ZkImZxiwt)

Consider `10 20 30 40 50 60`:

- `#\` Gives `1 2 3 4 5 6` (ie, 1...n).
- `#\##\` Uses that list to "copy" itself:

  ```
  1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6
  ```
- `#{.` Take only the first n elements of that:

  ```
  1 2 2 3 3 3
  ```
- `</.~` Group the original input using that mask:

  ```
  ┌──┬─────┬────────┐
  │10│20 30│40 50 60│
  └──┴─────┴────────┘
  ```

Comment: Nice approach! A Jelly port ties the existing 5-byte answer: `JxJ¹ƙ`.

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 18 bytes

Prompts for a vector of numbers or a string of characters. Outputs a nested vector.

```
(m↑(⍳m)/⍳m←⍴n)⊂n←⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv0buo7aJGo96N@dq6oNIoMyj3i15mo@6mvJA7L6p/4HquP6ncRkqGCkYK5gomCqYKZgrWChYKhgacAGFDRSMDBSMDRRMIDwQF8QHCRgomBqARNUTk5JTUtPSMzKz1LkA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>86</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>77</s></sup> 76 bytes

```c
r;i;f(a,n)int*a;{for(i=r=1;n--;r+=r*~r/2+i++?0:puts(""))printf("%d ",*a++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZLtasMgFIb/9yrOhIJGQ/PR7qPO9UK2MkLaFGGzJWYsrGSXvuzE2CXpnwmaeN7n@B7l5OEhz9u2lFoWNBOGaVMFmTwXx5JqVapYmjCUJVdl8F0uEq4530Tr00dlKSGMnUrkC0rmOyAiyDhnsmkxBO@ZNpTBeQY4ukC1t1X8vAUF51hAIiAVsBSwEnAr4E7AvYAHAXHUyElK4lMizMGZ4lxeM@mFcZCjHIbLKrqGX01PW/21PxbUlcUWfhf0WwEjNZmqyVRNp2rKBrvA@dnezh0s@iv1n9ST@NJAu@q02e1rZCPpfx/HRnZqZJkEzh13eeXBFg/prZ2@lWMZjFfxIbzswp1zPJBDVb4irMZIqLnCDlCqDmjN8d2SsXk3/hrCzndEgN7gQtYE1@pZb9lg0MyuUyB8ejFkhODFsSFH1RfU@96oJDDs0oUD0UfCf8Ylo5k17U9evGUH24afvw)

*Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*

Inputs a pointer to an array of integers and its length (because pointers in C carry no length info).
Outputs to `stdout` each array slice with the array elements separated by spaces and the slices separated by newlines.

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/index.html), <s>24</s> <s>22</s> <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 12 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Razetime, and -2 more bytes (and a BQN lesson) thanks to ovs*

```
 1↓⊢⊔˜≠⥊·/˜⊒˜
```

[Try it at BQN online REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=UmVwU2xpY2Ug4oaQIDHihpPiiqLiipTLnOKJoOKlisK3L8uc4oqSy5wKCmFycmF5IOKGkCDin6gxLDIsMyw0LDUsNiw3LDgsOSwxMOKfqQpSZXBTbGljZSBhcnJheQ==)

Comment: `∾⥊¨˜` becomes `/˜`

Comment: @Razetime - (1) Thanks for spotting; (2) Drat!  I'm sure I had it working in the REPL, but now I've lost how I did it (if at all...).  Replaced with a longer working version for now, while I try to fix the shorter one...  (3) And thanks v much for offer to help: I'll struggle a bit, and maybe ping you if I can't manage...

Comment: @Razetime - Fixed.  I'd somehow lost a ```˜```...

Comment: [`1↓⊢⊔˜≠⥊·/˜⊒˜`](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=I0bihpAgMeKGkyjipYrin5woL8uc4oaVKeKJoCniirjiipQKI0bihpAgMeKGk+KKouKKlMuc4qWK4p+cKC/LnOKGlSniiJjiiaAKI0bihpAgMeKGk+KKouKKlMuc4omg4qWKwrcvy5zCt+KGleKJoApGIOKGkCAx4oaT4oqi4oqUy5ziiaDipYrCty/LnOKKksucCgo+4ouI4p+cRsKoIOKfqDEr4oaVMTAKMTDDlzEr4oaVNAoxMDDDlzEr4oaVNeKfqQ==) saves 2 bytes; The link includes a few steps, but it is a combinations of [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238023/64121) and using *Nothing* to call a function monadically in a train.

Comment: @ovs - Thanks a lot, and especially for the steps, which I'm currently [struggling](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=YXJyYXkg4oaQIOKfqDEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsOCw5LDEw4p+pCkYg4oaQIDHihpPiiqLiipTLnOKJoOKlisK3L8uc4oqSy5wKCiMgRiBhcnJheSAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICMgdGhpcyB3b3JrcwojICgx4oaT4oqi4oqUy5ziiaDipYrCty/LnOKKksucKSBhcnJheSAgIyB0aGlzIHdvcmtzCjHihpPiiqLiipTLnOKJoOKlisK3L8uc4oqSy5wgYXJyYXkgICAgICAjIGJ1dCB0aGlzIGRvZXNuJ3Qgd29yay4gIHdoeT8K) to work-through...  I'll update the post once I manage to understand it (or once I give up...)

Comment: Ah I guess you haven't really looked at tacit functions / trains yet. In short the expression `1↓⊢⊔˜≠⥊·/˜⊒˜` on its own is a function, but if you add a value to the end it is a normal statement(?) instead. If you want to spend some time on function trains, the BQN documentation has [an introduction](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/doc/train.html) on it, but for now `1↓⥊⟜(/˜↕)∘≠⊸⊔` might be a simpler 1-byte saving.

Comment: @ovs - spent the afternoon reading the trains page, so this is a great intro 'in anger'.  I *think* I've got *most* of it, although I'm [still hazy](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=KCgxKSDihpMgKOKKoikg4oqUy5wgKOKJoOKKoikg4qWKICjCtykgL8ucICjiipLLnCkpIOKGlTEwICMgZXZlcnkgMm5kIGVsZW1lbnQgb2YgdHJhaW4gaW4gcGFyZW5zCigoMSkg4oaTICjiiqIpIOKKlMucICjiiaAgKSDipYogKMK3KSAvy5wgKOKKksucKSkg4oaVMTAgIyBzdGlsbCB3b3JrcyB3aXRob3V0IGFyZyBmb3Ig4omgCg==) about how ```≠``` gets its argument in the middle of the train

Comment: The functions you put in parens are all applied to the argument(s) of the entire train. `⊢` is not really the right argument of the train but rather a function that returns its right argument. `(≠⊢)` is a 2-train which calls `≠` on the result of `⊢` (Equivalent to `≠∘⊢` - *length atop right*). Because the entire train is only applied to an argument on the right, this has the same effect as a bare `≠` (If the train would be called with a left argument, `(≠⊢)` and `(≠)` wouldn't be equivalent).

Comment: Thanks!  Your first sentence here has cleared-up my understanding a lot.

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 92 bytes

```scala
a=>if(a.last.size>a.size)f(a.init++Seq(a.last.take(a.size))++Seq(a.last.drop(a.size)))else a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5La8MwEITv@RVzlMhi5Ef6Aht6LOTWSyDksE1kUCtk11pKSelvdy3TBgJpDjvL7nyzbNyz57F7ebV7wQb2U2w4RDz2Pb4WwAd7tA/q2b5vUz0F2e3q5mzUqDFy3bhWceY5Shbd0TY8N52WLjhZLqfAHyD8ZtUvoM@cw9D1J0dbHy14BPrBBfFBoU2vzJVTQSVVtKIbuqU7uqfcTBHoxWXcUGGoNFRdpwyhSFImqZKszNXEP57KIR2mezqTbu2izNj3@AM)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 45 bytes

```perl
sub{my@r;push@r,[splice@_,0,1+@r]while@_;\@r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9tS8MwEMff91Mco7Mtnix92lOpVtg7wYGIb9oy5ky34rrFpEXHnF@9Jm0paOCSu3/@97uEUb73az0La1G9notTxANWiV3EMRZsn29otEKC9nXE089dvpdlkET8UgdaduSmBhBDbCM4CC6Ch@AjjBEmCFOEGYJNUghvIY7tFCF20FWHhz6OVTLBKc5QelJIsWMRCZPhyvBk87/VskgDI@g2ife3vwE0hAYhN5/0oK6/AyhChyCoXA3HOktUcTL1/MBQp1/MCiN9FTSivj2W4ZWemZG6tZRYCQqLdbmezxdVwShXGuP5ocwGQyFHSl9VhsMbx1OVxNFNSd@k4DpKUMChSA4D9QGAlmGqORbQj75Wz4A7MI7vBszBeFw@w/LBaHuKNet9Kyv8EaNEfCf6y/2TDeFotOXYfwUVONAuWv0L)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 33 bytes

```
GatherBy[#,i=1;Round@√(2i++)&]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcjNCoJAFIbh/VxFIIgyRzwzaj/EhLRpG7WUFoMlzcITmS1CdN01dHndyOSQq@973lq310utW1NqWym7c2y2r8IDo8T6cHvSOf@@P4E0nIf@ybf7xlBbeNGmyr2TPxxLTUPHOgESEkghgzksYAkrENjD2BEkQoKQTnR2wRWEDLFnvaWAuAhjqQyjGXFScjpcxOkIN4zU494Ef4SRiCX7AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 11 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
⊜□⬚2↙⧻,⊚⇡⧻.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4oqc4pah4qyaMuKGmeKnuyziiprih6Hip7suCgpmIFszIDMgMyAzIDMgMyAzIDMgMyAzXQpmIFs1IDYgNyA4IDkgMTAgMTEgMTIgMTMgMTRdCmYgWzFdCmYgWzEgMl0KZiBbMSAyIDNdCmYgWzEgMiAzIDRd)

```
⊜□⬚2↙⧻,⊚⇡⧻.
          .  # duplicate
         ⧻   # length
        ⇡    # range
       ⊚     # where
      ,      # over
     ⧻       # length
  ⬚2↙        # take with fill element of 2
⊜□           # partition with boxing
```

Comment: If you want to handle [arrays with repeated elements](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4oqc4pah4qyaMuKGmeKnuyziipriipsuCgpmIFszIDMgMyAzIDMgM10KZiBbMyAzIDMgMyAzIDddCmYgWzMgMyAzIDMgMyA3IDhd), I think you'll need to swap 'classify' for 'range-length', or something like that...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks. Fixed for +1.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 47 bytes:

```
def f(l,c=1):
 while l:yield l[:c];l=l[c:];c+=1
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDoMgFAXAfU/xlpC@RVHbKoaTEFYIkeRHjZI0np7OHHdd961rbUkZWQmjM9o@8FuLJIi9S5IF4m0Mszjx0YY5Pp1px1m2qqRcVWXlDdERPTEQb@JDfImRmAjzClrr9gc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 71 bytes

```python
g=lambda x,s=1:[[c for c,_ in zip(x,range(s))]]+g(x[s:],s+1)if x else[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrBDsIgDADQX@mxdb003pbwJbUxOAFJJiOwA/rzePCdX/2cr6NcZ3S3mdzu34@nh8Hdyaq6QTwabHyHXOCbKw5uvqSAnchsSTi0r8Z9EcoRBoS9B7VZWy4nRtTLfwuLkBHNHw)

*-3* Thanks to @U12-Forward

Comment: [71 bytes! -3 swapping the order of `if` and `else` statements](https://tio.run/##JcrBDsIgDADQX@mxdb003pbwJbUxOAFJJiOwA/rzePCdX/2cr6NcZ3S3mdzu34@nh8Hdyaq6QTwabHyHXOCbKw5uvqSAnchsSTi0r8Z9EcoRBoS9B7VZWy4nRtTLfwuLkBHNHw).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 42 bytes

*-2 thanks to @emanresuA because I'm a potato*

```
x=>(f=n=>x+x&&[x.splice(0,++n),...f(n)])``
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-xp`, 12 bytes

```
a^@$+*\,\,#a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgebSSbkWBUuyCpaUlaboWaxLjHFS0tWJ0YnSUEyFCUJmt0UrRhtZG1sbWJtam1mbW5tYWsXBtAA)

#### Explanation

```
a^@$+*\,\,#a
          #a  Length(argument)
        \,    Inclusive range from 1 to ^
      \,      Inclusive range from 1 to each number in ^
   $+*        Sum each
a^@           Split argument at those indices
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 74 bytes

```
a=>(0 to a.size).map(i=>a.slice(i*(i+1)/2,(i+1)*(i+2)/2)).filter(_.size>0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9PC4JAEMXvfoo57tRg66r9A4WOQbcuQUhstsLGpqZLRNFnN9dbUB3mDT/mvRmmzaWRXXU8q9zCDtTdqvLUwqqu4ekB3KSBYsm26rp3tS5tliXpByIk0MkkZRxsBdJv9UOhf5E100nao9G5YnrE9DjAiaChOxI9IfqFNlY17DDkUo4dQN3o0pqSQeEODxWQoJAiimlKM5rTggKOiIDedzsnwSnkFP13cQLhJHQSOYn538SPGQvc7/0@9G210a0dbK/uDQ)

The obvious way to avoid the filter at the end is to make the range from 0 to the biggest triangle number whose value is less than `a.size`, but the shortest way I could find to express that in Scala 2.13 was longer than the thing it was supposed to replace:

```
BigDecimal(0).until(pow(2*a.size+.25,.5)-.5,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 22 bytes

```
*.rotor(1..*,:partial)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfS68ovyS/SMNQT09Lx6ogsagkMzFH87@1QnFipYKSSrxeAVC5hqaCrZ1CdZqGSrymXnpmcUmtkkJafpGCA0iboYGmjoKGoYGOghEQGwOxCVQELAQWAwsCCVMDA83/AA)

The `rotor` method splits an array into chunks of a given size or sizes, eg:

- `rotor(5)` splits an array into 5-element chunks.
- `rotor(2, 3)` splits an array into chunks of alternating sizes 2 and 3.

Here, I pass the infinite range `1 .. *` as the argument, so `rotor` will emit chunks of sizes 1, 2, 3, ....  The `:partial` keyword argument causes all remaining elements to be grouped into the final chunk, even if there aren't enough of them.

Answer (score 0):

## APL (Dyalog Unicode), 17 bytes

This is a dfn that takes a vector as a right argument. It groups segments per specification into a nested array of vectors.

```
{⍵⊆⍨1+q⍸⍨+\q←⍳⍴⍵}
```

The index origin is set to 0 (⎕IO←0).

[Try it on TryAPL.org!](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=%E2%8E%95IO%E2%86%900%E2%8B%84%7B%E2%8D%B5%E2%8A%86%E2%8D%A81%2Bq%E2%8D%B8%E2%8D%A8%2B%5Cq%E2%86%90%E2%8D%B3%E2%8D%B4%E2%8D%B5%7D1%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%2010%2011%2012%2013%2014%2015%2016&run)

This was an interesting challenge and demonstrates that there are many ways to get to a solution in the APL language. None I found had a lesser byte count, but the approaches may be of interest:

by recursion: {⍺←1 ⋄ ⍺≥⍴⍵:⊂⍵ ⋄ (⊂⍺↑⍵),(⍺+1)∇ ⍺↓⍵}

by formula: {⍵⊆⍨⌊0.5+0.5*⍨2×⍳⍴⍵}

by iteration: {p⊆⍨q↑∊{⍵⍴⍵}¨⍳q←⍴⍵}